# How to extend a Java class with a loaded class?

Tags: java

I am injecting a Applet that way that it can't check on which website it is.
The purpose is to load an external unmodified applet into mine so I can embed it into mine.

```
    final URL[] appletURL = { new URL(Main.getBase() + "/loader.jar") };
    final URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(appletURL); // gets the class
    final Class<?> loader = classLoader.loadClass("loader"); // loads the class
    applet = (Applet) loader.newInstance(); // creates the applet
    applet.setStub(new Injector()); // injects the getdocumentbase, so it thinks he is on his own website
    applet.init(); // start applet
    applet.start();
    applet.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); // to be able to add to jframe properly
```

The "applet.setStub(new Injector());" part is to prevent navigating away or not loading because it's not the applet's own website.
But now I want to render the external applet to a screenshot.
I tried this:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    final String s = e.getActionCommand();
    if (s.equals("Screenshot")) {
        final BufferedImage offScreen = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        applet.update(offScreen.createGraphics());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(offScreen, "PNG", new File("C:/Users/Mitchell/Pictures/screenshot.png"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {  }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't use the paint nor updat method.
It uses getGraphics() instead, I got tipped to extend the applet that I want to screenshot.
But the applet is dynamically loaded, so how do I extend a class with a loaded class (or applet)?

Can someone provide a code sample?
I am about to freak out because this is taking all my time and I can't continue without this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would you like to do?

Comment: Sjoerd: I guess something like (hypothetical) `myVar.getClass().addField("foobar", "java.lang.String")`

Comment: I believe they're asking how to do monkey patching in Java.

Comment: I think he wants to extend his class with another field. Either way, this can be done via reflection.

Comment: You can't modify a class or create a class with reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [cglib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/).

If instead of a class you want to extend, you want to implement an interface, take a look at [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you just add a field dynamically or otherwise, there won't be any code which uses it which is rather pointless,(except for access via reflection)

If you want a object with dynamic field names, perhaps a `Map<String, Object>` is what you really want.

---

You can extends a class which has an additional fields any number of ways provided its not final.

You can do this at compile time, you can compile code at runtime, you can add a class from generated byte code at runtime.

If you know you need to extend a class, write the code to do that and you don't need to generate anything.

Comment: He never said anything about adding a field (it was another user). That's not very useful but implementing interfaces dynamically at runtime is used a lot in frameworks and runtime subclassing is also heavily used in mocking libraries.

Comment: It is for access via reflection XD

Comment: In that case you can dynamically compile generated code or use a byte code generator like ObjectWeb's ASM.